# How to configure a WordPress blog to save uploaded images to a certain dir.?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress blog installed on my server but when i upload a image it goes into one directory, but the blog front end is looking for the images in another directory, so the images show as broken. I have been manually copying the uploaded images from server location to the one WP looks for them in and it works.

How can i set the WP blog to upload to the same dir on the filesystem that the WP front end is trying to pull from?

Comment: Can you show the directory path WP uses to upload, and the one it points to in the front-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely WordPress failing to correctly guess the upload path and URL.

Go to `Settings` > `Miscellaneous` and hardcode the correct path and full URL.

Comment: i am new to WP, do i need an admin account to do this?

Comment: When you installed WP, you were given a username 'admin' and a password - this will be an admin account. Log in to WP using these details and follow my answer :)